# How to send a message MessageGroupID and MessageDeduplicationID to amazonSQS using camel-aws

Tags: java, amazon-sqs, apache-camel-aws

Could we send a message to Amazon SQS "FIFO" queue using the Java-DSL syntax:

```
from("..")..to("aws-sqs://testSQSFifo.fifo?amazonSQSClient=#amazonSQSClient);
```

Keep in mind that: this is a FIFO queue, so it needs MessageGroupID and MessageDeduplicationID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use the following syntax:

```
from("..")..to("aws-sqs://testSQSFifo.fifo?amazonSQSClient=#amazonSQSClient&amp;messageGroupIdStrategy=STRATEGY);
```

where **STRATEGY** can be one of the following options: **useConstant**, **useExchangeId**, **usePropertyValue**. For the usePropertyValue option, the value of property CamelAwsMessageGroupId will be used.

see: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-aws-sqs/src/main/docs/aws-sqs-component.adoc